# App.TaskVisible equivalent code for VB.net

Tags: vb.net

anyone knows the equivalent code for **App.TaskVisible** in VB.net? App.TaskVisible is from VB6 which hides the application in the **applications list** in task manager and not in the processes list tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in .NET for a program which is already running.  You can hide it from the task bar by using `Window.ShowInTaskBar = False`, but it will still be visible in the Applications list.

You could create your application as a Windows Service - services are not shown in the Applications list.

You could also write code to run the program in a new process.